# Real time Moving Averages in Python

Tags: python, average

I need to calculate moving average of a sensor data that is coming on on the serial port with Python. All the samples I can find about numpy use data from a file or hard coded data in an array before the program starts.

In my case I do not have any data when the program starts. The data comes in real time in every second. I want to smooth the data as it arrives on the serial port.

I have this working on the Arduino but also need it in Python. Can somebody please point me to a real time (single value over time) sample not a batch sample.

Comment: So you have only one value per second?  I'd simply implement an [exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) in Python.  It's about one line of code, maybe two.

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. It has practical value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you would add one reading at a time to a running collection of readings and return the average. I prepopulated the readings list to show it in action, but in your program, you'd just start off with an empty list: `readings = []`

I made the assumption that you want to include the last x readings in your average rather than including all of the readings.  That is what the `max_samples` parameter is for.

without numpy:

```
readings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
reading = 10
max_samples = 10

def mean(nums):
    return float(sum(nums)) / max(len(nums), 1)

readings.append(reading)
avg = mean(readings)

print 'current average =', avg
print 'readings used for average:', readings

if len(readings) == max_samples:
    readings.pop(0)

print 'readings saved for next time:', readings
```

result:

```
current average = 5.5
readings used for average: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
readings saved for next time: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

readings = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
reading = 10
max_samples = 10

readings = np.append(readings, reading)
avg = np.mean(readings)

print 'current average =', avg
print 'readings used for average:', readings

if len(readings) == max_samples:
    readings = np.delete(readings, 0)

print 'readings saved for next time:', readings
```

result:

```
current average = 5.5
readings used for average: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
readings saved for next time: [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

Answer (score 7):

Implemented as a class:

```
class StreamingMovingAverage:
    def __init__(self, window_size):
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.values = []
        self.sum = 0

    def process(self, value):
        self.values.append(value)
        self.sum += value
        if len(self.values) > self.window_size:
            self.sum -= self.values.pop(0)
        return float(self.sum) / len(self.values)
```